# Creating game UI. Problems with pixels

Tags: android, user-interface

How should I create UI for android games? Should I use layout XML file?

I used html for few apps I have made and it was easier approach to create scalable UI (but that was no games). How to make UI scalable without using HTML?

Also problem with pixels: every canvas on every phone is different in width X height so if I put something in lets say [100,100] (px) position it doesn't have to be on same position (depends on phone to phone) and if I create program on my phone what will happen with it on tablet or on phone with bigger resolution?

Is there any way bypassing it?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite chaotic, but as  for pixels - you need to [read here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) as screen **density** is what you need to consider in your calculations. You can (depending on your code) use dimension resources or do the math yourself (device's screen density can be read from [DisplayMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#densityDpi)'s densityDpi field:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
```

Comment: But if I have arts for lets say phone resolution 800x300 and if resolution is higher just resize image multiplication it with dm ?

Comment: You should rather have arts (assets) for **density**, not resolution. At least for `mdpi` and `hdpi`. If you have just `mdpi` then it will look bit blurry on higher densities (sideeffect of upscaling). Sometimes it is not a problem, but for games graphics is important so you shall pay attention

Comment: Possibly. Alternatively you design your bitmap art for highest possible (supported) density and then scale it down to prepare assets for lower as scaling down is better option than scaling up